# How to delete leading newline in a string in bash?

Tags: bash

I'm having the following issue. I have an array of numbers:

```
text="\n1\t2\t3\t4\t5\n6\t7\t8\t9\t0"
```

And I'd like to delete the leading newline.
I've tried

```
sed 's/.//' <<< "$text"
cut -c 1- <<< "$text"
```

and some iterations. But the issue is that both of those delete the first character AFTER EVERY newline. Resulting in this:

```
text="\n\t2\t3\t4\t5\n\t7\t8\t9\t0"
```

This is not what I want and there doesn't seem to be an answer to this case.

Is there a way to tell either of those commands to treat newlines like characters and the entire string as one entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
awk 'NR>1'
```

of course you can do the same with `tail -n +2` or `sed 1d` as well.

Comment: I suspect that I do not understnad the question completely, but for now it looks like only a simple `var="${var#$'\n'}"` is needed here.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use the substitution modifier (see [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) and [ANSI C quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) in the Bash manual):

```
$ text=$'\n1\t2\t3\t4\t5\n6\t7\t8\t9\t0'
$ echo "$text"

1   2   3   4   5
6   7   8   9   0
$ echo "${text/$'\n'/}"
1   2   3   4   5
6   7   8   9   0
$
```

It replaces the first newline with nothing, as requested.  However, note that it is not anchored to the first character:

```
$ alt="${text/$'\n'/}"
$ echo "${alt/$'\n'/}"
1   2   3   4   56  7   8   9   0
$
```

Using a caret `^` before the newline doesn't help — it just means there's no match.

As pointed out by [rici](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1566221/rici) in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34971696/how-to-delete-leading-newline-in-a-string-in-bash/34971774?noredirect=1#comment57673967_34971774), if you read the manual page I referenced, you can find how to anchor the pattern at the start with a `#` prefix:

```
$ echo "${text/#$'\n'/}"
1   2   3   4   5
6   7   8   9   0
$ echo "${alt/#$'\n'/}"
1   2   3   4   5
6   7   8   9   0
$
```

The notation bears no obvious resemblance to other regex systems; you just have to know it.

Comment: To anchor the pattern, use `#`. I know, I know, bash is weird. Quoting man bash: "If `pattern` begins with `#`, it must match at the beginning of the expanded value of `parameter`.  If `pattern` begins with `%`, it must match at the end of the expanded value of `parameter`.

Comment: Such a close relationship to all the other regex systems.  Yeah, I'd not read that again.